# Why make second stage current larger than input stage current in op-amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, constant-current

When people speak about the slew-rate of a Miller-compensated op-amp, the usual derivation is that the slew rate is approximately the input tail current divided by the Miller capacitance. E.g. [here (slide 16)](https://slideplayer.com/slide/9174642/):

The bottom right of that slide contains the important note, that this only applies if the intermediate stage current is higher than the input stage current.

**My Question is**, why this is implied. The input stage current is decisive for op-amp noise, so wouldn't one generally try to dedicate as much of the quiescent current budget to the input stage as possible ?

Comment: It's a video you linked and I can't see slide numbers. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @Andyaka yes..Click Slideshow right under the viewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum current available for charging and discharging Cc is either the first stage current or the second stage current, whichever is smallest of the two. So the slew-rate roughly depends on the value of Cc and whichever is the smaller out of first and second stage currents.

Presumably the second stage current would be set to a level based on required output current provision or, in the case of a more conventional op amp, set to a level high enough to provide enough base current to the output stage transistors when the amplifier is under full load. With regard to slew rate, there would be little point increasing the input stage current above the value of the second stage current because slew-rate would be limited by the smaller of the two. This is a very basic view of what determines slew-rate which in reality will depend on more factors than just the value of Cc and the input stage tail current (or second stage current if it's smaller than the input stage tail current).

I suppose a reason for increasing first stage current above the amount of second stage current would be to improve input stage transconductance thereby improving open loop gain. But this may not be advantageous if you want to keep the amplifier unity gain stable because you'd need to increase the size of Cc to reduce the open loop gain back down if it became too high in value for unity gain.

Increasing the size of the input stage current above the size of the second stage may not have significant benefits but will increase the power requirements for the amplifier.

That slide does say "usually".

Comment: Thanks for the insights. I was too focused on noise alone.